# Allow only one interval to run at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an app that constantly (every 3 seconds) checks a Database and writes the result as a table in HTML using jQuery.ajax(). I also have a nav bar where you choose what information to load on the table, like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="showPlaces">Mesas</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="showReservations">Reservaciones</button>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="result_table">

            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And I got the script that makes it work:

```
var interval;

function showPlaces(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'places.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#result_table').html(result);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call    
}

function showReservations(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'res.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#result_table').html(result);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call   
}

function stopUpdate(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#showPlaces').click(function(){
        stopUpdate(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function(){ showPlaces()} , 3000);
    });

    $('#showReservations').click(function(){
        stopUpdate(interval);
        inverval = setInterval(function() { showReservations()}, 3000); 
    });
});
```

When I run this I get no errors, once one of the buttons is pressed the interval repeats indefinetly (this I want), If I press both they start rewriting each other every three seconds (I don't want!), shouldn't the stopUpdate function stop execution of the interval once either button is pressed? The answer might be obvious but i'm prety new to async websites

Comment: your ajax requests are probably stacking up and there are a few still awaiting a response when you hit stop, when they come in they over write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got typo here:

**inverval** = setInterval(function() { showReservations()}, 3000);

inverval instead interval

Comment: Wow this is awkward, but I'm glad is was so simple, Thank you @Ncx !. Anyone knows a nice IDE that can catch this kind of things before I make a fool of myself on the internet?

Comment: Don't worry, it happens. I'm using phpstorm, I've checked and it highlights not defined "inverval".